# Convert integer to byte array produces unexepected results

Tags: c, hex, printf, byte

OK...this seems like a fairly easy problem but I can't figure out what is going on here.  I have the following code to convert an integer to a byte array and test the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void int2bytearray(char *byte_array, int size, int num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {   
        byte_array[i] = (num >> 8*i) & 0xFF;
    }   
}

int main()
{
    int test_int = 657850;
    int size = sizeof(int);
    
    printf("Size is %d\n", size);
    printf("Size of char is %d\n", (int)sizeof(char));
    
    char test_array[size];
    
    printf("Size of first entry %d\n", (int)sizeof(test_array[0]));

    int2bytearray(test_array, size, test_int);
    
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {   
        printf("%#02x", test_array[i]);
    }   

    printf("\nFirst byte is %#.2X", test_array[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect main to return an array of *bytes*, but the first "byte" appears to be a 32 bit integer.

Unfortunately, I get the following output:

```
Size is 4
Size of char is 1
Size of first entry 1
0xffffffba0x90xa00
First byte is 0XFFFFFFBA
```

Can someone tell me why this first byte is printing out as `0XFFFFFFBA`?  Why is it a 32-bit integer and not a byte as defined?

Comment: Because bit-fiddling with *signed* types requires extra caution and results are implementation defined in the best case. Work with unsigned integers if it is aligned with what you are trying to do.

Comment: `char test_array[size];` is probably `signed`. So any parts of the original value that have bit 7 set are negative, and are sign-extended to 32-bits for output. Format `%X` handles 32-bit values, and any smaller type is promoted to 32-bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related both to the type being used and how you're printing the values.

The first element in the array has value `0xBA` which as a signed `char` is -70 in decimal.  When this value is passed to `printf` it is converted to type `int`, so now you have a 32 bit value of -70 whose representation is `0XFFFFFFBA` you then print it using %X it which prints an  `unsigned int` in hex.

There are two ways to fix this.

First, change the type of `test_array` to `unsigned char`.  Then the values stored will be positive and print correctly.  The other option is to use `%hhX` as the format specifier which states to print the value as an `unsigned char` which will print the proper number of digits.